# Unable to change the texture of SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

In my game I am creating a Circle object with a certain texture but for example if the Circle hits a certain wall, I want its texture to change. Unfortunately that does not work for some reason and I have no idea why.
This is my code for the Circle class:

```
class Circle: SKNode, GKAgentDelegate{
    let txtName = "farblos"

    var node: SKSpriteNode {
        let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: txtName)
        node.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        node.name = "circle"

        return node
    }

    let agent: GKAgent2D

    init(position: CGPoint) {
        agent = GKAgent2D()
        agent.position = vector_float2(x: Float(position.x), y: Float(position.y))
        agent.radius = Float(15)
        agent.maxSpeed = 50.0
        agent.maxAcceleration = 20.0
        super.init()

        self.position = position
        agent.delegate = self
        addChild(node)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Just for testing purposes I added this piece of code directly after adding the node as a child node.

```
node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "cyan")
```

There is no error when loading the texture. The image definitely exists and I can create a SKTexture from it.

Do you have any idea why the texture doesn't change?

This is how the Circle object is created:

```
for _ in 1...i {
    let entity = Circle(position: CGPoint.randomPoint(inBounds: b, notCollidingWith: allBoundaries))

    agentSystem.addComponent(entity.agent)
    allCircles.append(entity)

    self.addChild(entity)
}
```

This code is being executed in the didMoveTo method from the scene.

At collision time, this is my code:

```
override func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact, with circle: Circle) {
    circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.allExcept(c).rawValue
    circle.node.texture = txt
}
```

txt is created here:

```
var txt: SKTexture{
        get{
            return SKTexture(imageNamed: c)
        }
    }
```

c is a String with the value "cyan"

Comment: when you change it to cyan does it work?

Comment: No the texture dosen't change from farblos

Comment: don't include code n your question that is not relevant to the question. It makes it harder to read and decipher what is happening.

Comment: Ok, I will remember that

Comment: can you show the code where you try to change the texture after collision. Saying that you try to change the texture to cyan is fine, but you don't give any context as to where in the code you try this. you need to show the code where the object is created as well

Comment: can you show the code where you set "txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with this bit...

```
var node: SKSpriteNode {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: txtName)
    node.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    node.name = "circle"

    return node
}
```

every time you access node you are reassigning the texture "txtName"

it needs to be...

```
lazy var node: SKSpriteNode = {
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: txtName)
    node.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    node.name = "circle"

    return node
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work, in my opinion, is because of the calculated value of "node" variable.

What you are doing is creating a new node whenever you reference the "node" variable. When you do `addChild(node)`
you are doing 2 things: create a new Node then add it as a child of the scene.

So, if you do
`node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "cyan")`
you are creating a new node and setting its texture, but this is NOT the same node you added to the scene.

to avoid this, save the created node in a variable and use the variable to set the new texture.

It worked for me :) hope this helps